# Two properties about the sequence $u_n:= v_n +\alpha t_n$, with $v_n$ and $t_n$ bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $(v_n)_n$, $(t_n)_n$ be two sequences such that $(v_n)_n$ is bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(t_n)_n$ is a real bounded sequence. Let
$$u_n:= v_n +\alpha t_n \quad\mbox{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N},$$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
During the math class, the professor said that the above relation ensures that, given $\varepsilon>0$, a constant $c(\varepsilon)>0$ exists such that:
$$(1)\qquad\qquad u_n^2 \ge (1-\varepsilon)t_n^2 \alpha^2-c(\varepsilon) v_n^2,$$
$$(2)\qquad\qquad \lim_n\|u_n\|^2 \le (1+\varepsilon)\lim_n t_n^2,$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the norm in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Could someone please help me to understand why these 2 relations actually hold true?
Thank you in advance.

${\bf EDIT:}$ For the inequality $(2)$ some changes are needed in my above writing. To prove that $(2)$ holds, in math class we referred to $u_n:= v_n+t_n w_n$, with $\|w_n\|=1$ (I apologize with psl2Z whom was trying with the wrong one sequence).
I'd proceed in this way
$$\|u_n\|^2 =\int_{\Omega}|\nabla (v_n+t_n w_n)|^2 dx\le \|v_n\|^2 +t_n^2.$$
Actually, I don’t even understand here the role of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: For (1) use $-2ab \leq a^2 +b^2$

Comment: @psl2Z thank you. Actually it is not clear for me the role of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Actually i don't see why (2) should hold, because if we take $t_n = 0$, and $v_n = u_n = v \neq 0$ constant in $H_0^1$ then (2) implies $0 = u_n = v \neq 0$? Further i don't see, why $(t_n),(u_n)$  should converge? Do you mean $\limsup$? Moreover $u_n$ is not $0$ on boundary if $t_n$ is not $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For (1): for every $\varepsilon > 0$: $-2\alpha t_n v_n \leq \varepsilon (\alpha t_n)^2 + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}v_n^2$, therefore $u_n^2 = (\alpha t_n)^2 + 2\alpha t_n v_n + v_n^2 \geq (1-\varepsilon)\alpha^2 t_n^2 - (\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1)v_n^2$. If $\epsilon < 1$ then $C(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1 > 0$, otherwise the inequality is clear.

Comment: psl2Z thank you for the answer. I edited the question for the inequality $(2)$, I apologize. Moreover, if possible, I'd ask why you used $\varepsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. I agree with $2ab\le a^2 +b^2$, but I don't "see" why it remains true by multiplying for $\varepsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ (I apologize if it is a dumb question).

Comment: $-2ab = -2(\sqrt{\varepsilon}a)(\frac{b}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}) \leq (\sqrt{\varepsilon}a)^2 + (\frac{b}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}})^2 = \varepsilon a^2 + \frac{b^2}{\varepsilon}$